# Why am I not able to get each data of these?

Tags: c++, string

I'd like to get each data of Name, Subject, Grade but I'm not able to get data of Name because getting data of Name have been ignore and it has been gone on to getting data of Subject.

Here's my source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int TheNumofStd = 0;

struct Subject
{
    char *Subname;
    int Credit;
    char *Grade;
    float GPA;
};

struct Student
{
    char *StdName;
    int StdID;
    Subject* Sub;
    int SubNum;
    float AveGPA;
};
int main()
{
    getStdName();
    getSubjectName();
    getGrade();

  return 0;
}
string getStdName()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Name : ";
    
    getline(cin, name);
    return name;
}
string getSubjectName()
{
    string subname;
    cout << "Subject : ";
    
    getline(cin, subname);
    return subname;
}
string getGrade()
{
    string grade;
    cout << "Grade(A+ ~ F) : ";
    
    getline(cin, grade);
    cout << "\n\n";
    return grade;
}
```

The result I want to print is getting each data of Name, Subject and Grade

Comment: Your functions read data and return it, but you're not using that return value for anything.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of your functions when you call them. Perhaps you intended to save it in a local variable.  eg.: `string name = getStdName();`

Comment: Even so, your structs are holding `char*` pointers, but your functions are returning `std::string` objects. Why? That is a potential recipe for disaster, depending on how you use those `char*` pointers. Just use `std::string` for everything instead.